# Como validar modelos en una lista ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

En el proyecto que estoy desarrollando cargo un archivo xlsx y me devuelve una lista de un modelo y tengo que mostrar si en la lsita existe un modelo con error, hasta ahora ya resolvi el problema, pero me gustaria saber si existe una mejor forma de resolver esto

**Funcion para leer el archivo**
En esat funcion se carga el archivo excel y retorna una lista del modelo TMP_CITAS,
para validar el modelo se llama la funcion **Validator(citas)** donde cargamos el modelo resultante de leer una fila del archivo excel, la funcion validator retorna una lista de la clase ERRORS que es añadida al modelo de cita

```
public ActionResult ReadFile(HttpPostedFileBase ARCHIVO)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!PermisoUsuario().NUEVO) return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");

            string[] formatos = { ".xlsx", ".XLSX" };
            string FileExtension = ARCHIVO != null ? System.IO.Path.GetExtension(ARCHIVO.FileName) : null;
            if (ARCHIVO == null)
            {
                return Content("<div class='alert alert-danger'><span>El campo Archivo es obligatorio</span></div>");
            }
            else
            if (!Array.Exists(formatos, x => x == FileExtension))
            {
                return Content("<div class='alert alert-danger'><span>El ARCHIVO tiene formato invalido, formato valido(xlsx)</span></div>");
            }
            
            var package = new ExcelPackage(ARCHIVO.InputStream);
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
            int colCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;
            int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;

            var citas = new List<TMP_CITAS>();
            for (int row = 2; row <= rowCount; row++)
            {
                var cita = new TMP_CITAS();

                cita.T_CITA_ID = Guid.NewGuid();
                cita.VIN = worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value?.ToString().Trim();
                cita.TELEFONO1 = worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value?.ToString().Trim();
                cita.TELEFONO2 = worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value?.ToString().Trim();
                cita.TELEFONO3 = worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value?.ToString().Trim();
                cita.CORREO = worksheet.Cells[row, 5].Value?.ToString().Trim();
                cita.CLIENTE = worksheet.Cells[row, 6].Value?.ToString().Trim();
                cita.VEHICULO = worksheet.Cells[row, 7].Value?.ToString().Trim();
                cita.COLOR = worksheet.Cells[row, 8].Value?.ToString().Trim();
                cita.SUCURSAL = worksheet.Cells[row, 9].Value?.ToString().Trim();
                cita.ORIGEN = "SIMETRICAL";
                cita.USUARIO_ID = UserIdentity().USUARIO_ID;
                cita.ERRORS = Validator(cita);

                if (cita.VIN != null || cita.CLIENTE != null || cita.VEHICULO != null || cita.COLOR != null || cita.SUCURSAL != null)
                {
                    citas.Add(cita);

                }
                
            }
            return View(citas);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Content("<div class='alert aler-danger'><span>"+ e.Message+"</span></div>");
        }
        
    }
```

**Funcion para validar el modelo**

```
private List<ERRORS> Validator(object model)
    {
        List<ERRORS> lista = new List<ERRORS>();
        if (!TryValidateModel(model))
        {
            foreach(var error in ModelState)
            {
                lista.Add(new ERRORS { KEY = error.Key, ERROR = error.Value.Errors[0].ErrorMessage });
            }
            ModelState.Clear();
        }

        return lista;
    }
```

**Modelos**

```
public partial class TMP_CITAS
{
    [Key]
    public Guid T_CITA_ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(17)]
    public string VIN { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string TELEFONO1 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string TELEFONO2 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string TELEFONO3 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string CORREO { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string CLIENTE { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string VEHICULO { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string COLOR { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string SUCURSAL { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string ORIGEN { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid USUARIO_ID { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<ERRORS> ERRORS { get; set; }
} 

public partial class ERRORS
{
    public string KEY { get; set; }
    public string ERROR { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual seria el problema?

Comment: Si hay maneras por ejemplo si son muchos registros puedes hacer en paralelo la validacion, tambien separar, la parte de validacion, lectura, agrega una clase ServicioArchivo en donde tengas las operaciones de lectura, validacion, errores, para que se entienda mejor tu codigo,.. Agrega tu codigo en algun compilador en linea para hacer comentarios ya que hay varias cosas que puedes cambiar y seguir reglas de codificacion